# can i set the width and margin without set the float left or rigth

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to increase the width and set the margin for a tag but it's not working without put float , can any one give any solution this is the code

```
.float-right .createAccount{
float: left;
margin-left: -11px;
width: 140px;}
```

Comment: You need to give us a bit more information about why it isn't working, floating an element has nothing to do with its width or margin

Comment: What kind of element is `.createAccount `?

Comment: i mean if i remove float:left it will not work is there any solution to set this property without using float ??

Comment: >>createaccount is anchor tag<< then set display:block; to the anchor

Comment: display :block also effect another anchor tag and the design damage ..

Comment: '<div class="float-right btn btn-warning"><a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; margin-left: -14px; width: 143px;" class="createAccount" href="#">+ Add your account</a></div>'
this is my code can i access add your account anchor without acssesing all createacount class in page ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
position:absolute
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:block`

```
.createAccount{
float: left;
margin-left: -11px;
width: 140px;
display:block}
```

Comment: display:block also effect another anchor and destroy the design

Comment: @dean provide the jsfiddle or link ... this question does not make much sense

Comment: try removing width and margin-left. and fix it by its parent div

Comment: <div class="float-right btn btn-warning"><a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; margin-left: -14px; width: 143px;" class="createAccount" href="#">+ add your account</a></div>

this is my code how to access the add your account anchor without effcting all createaccount classes in page ??

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin and width to any element but,

if you are using it for a inline elements (eg:- p, a, span) you have to add CSS property display : inline-block;

if you are using it for a block level elements (eg:- div, h2) you have to add CSS property display : block;

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;`

```
.createAccount {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -11px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

Comment: display: inline-block; same effect to another anchor same class 
design destroy like this

Comment: <div class="float-right btn btn-warning"><a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; margin-left: -14px; width: 143px;" class="createAccount" href="#">+ add your account</a></div> this is my code how to access the add your account anchor without effcting all createaccount classes in page ??